# PBYTE to PVOID error

Tags: c++, detours

I'm currently programming in Detours Express 3.0. I've first had some problems finding out how to use Detours, for example, I didn't know, that `DetourFunction()` was replaced with `DetourAttach()`. So, now I found it out, but somehow it still doesn't works and give me following errors:

> IntelliSense: argument of type "PBYTE *" is incompatible with
>   parameter of type "PVOID *"
>
> IntelliSense: argument of type "PBYTE *" is incompatible with
>   parameter of type "PVOID *"

```
//GuiShapeNameHud::OnRender
OriginalRender = (onRenderFn)DetourAttach((PBYTE*)(&OnRender), 
                 (PBYTE)Hooked_OnRender);

//input stuff
OriginalGetNextMove = (GetNextMoveFn)DetourAttach((PBYTE*)(&BLGetNextMove),
                      (PBYTE)Hooked_GetNextMove);
```

Comment: Try to cast them into `(PVOID*)`.

Comment: Thank you, but now I get a:
Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class CBLHackv300Module _AtlModule" Error.

Comment: You may have other problem then just the API change.